# HTML text not showing up

Tags: html, css

I've been stuck on this and trying to troubleshoot. Also, very new to coding going through a bootcamp, this is apart of the first "test" and I'm very confused at this point. What am I missing something here..

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
<div id="banner"></div>


html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    background: url("bg.jpeg");
    background-color:powderblue;
    background-size: auto 100%;
}

#banner {
    position:fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: -1;
}
h1 {
    text-align: center;
}


<h1>header</h1>
<h2>babble babble</h2>
<br>

    <li><a href="https://instagram.com"target="source"><img src="instagram.png" alt="Instagram" style="width:42px;height:42px:"></li></a>
    <li><a href="https://facebook.com"target="source"><img src="facebook.png" alt="Facebook" style="width:42px;height:42px:"></li></a>
    <li><a href="https://linkedin.com"target="source"><img src="linkedin.png" alt="LinkedIn" style="width:42px;height:42px:"></li></a>
    <li><a href="https://twitter.com"target="source"><img src="twitter.png" alt="Twitter" style="width:42px;height:42px:"></li></a>

</style>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: you have to put all the css inside `<style></style>` tag

Comment: wow, thank you! i feel so silly. i appreciate you!

Comment: no problem. That how we all learn - from ours mistakes :)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to your coding journey! Let me see if I can help.

I think the main issue you have going on here is that you have elements with the `style` tags in your `head` tags. For the elements to render onto the page, you need to move them into a `<body>` tag.

Here is an example to inspect to move in the right direction. There are still lots of things in there to troubleshoot.

```css
<!-- This is your css styles -->

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: url("bg.jpeg");
  background-color: powderblue;
  background-size: auto 100%;
}

#banner {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: -1;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="banner">Banner</div>
  <h1>header</h1>
  <h2>babble babble</h2><br>
  <li>
    <a href="https://instagram.com" target="source"><img src="instagram.png" alt="Instagram" style="width:42px;height:42px:"></li>
  </a>
  <li>
    <a href="https://facebook.com" target="source"><img src="facebook.png" alt="Facebook" style="width:42px;height:42px:"></li>
  </a>
  <li>
    <a href="https://linkedin.com" target="source"><img src="linkedin.png" alt="LinkedIn" style="width:42px;height:42px:"></li>
  </a>
  <li>
    <a href="https://twitter.com" target="source"><img src="twitter.png" alt="Twitter" style="width:42px;height:42px:"></li>
  </a>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: should be a comment

Comment: Thank you for your insight. I am currently inspecting and this helped me tons!

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a lot in this code.
The `<body>` is missing, the `<head>` nesting is wrong, and you don't seem to know where to put the `<style>`. `<ul>` is also missing.
I could provide code with everything fixed, but I don't think this will help in the long run.
Here are some samples. Hope this helps you to see the structure.

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
/*
CSS codes are here, between  style ~ style */
element {
  value
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>It needs BODY</h1>

  <ul>
    <li>&lt;li&gt; needs mother (&lt;ul&gt;)</li>
  </ul>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I appreciate you not giving me the out right answer. I do want to learn on my own. However your answer is very helpful and useful.